# Adding a View without a model MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to create a simple view with 3 links on it ( Administration type page ), I tried adding a View called index to a Directory called Administration but when I try to navigate to it it throws a resource not found error. I am brand new to MVC coming from Web Forms so sorry if this is a stupid question ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firts Add a controller which will come with Index method. Right click on Index Method and select Add View.
Add all Html you want to add in that view and your page is ready without adding a Model.

Comment: Thanks! I really am liking MVC versus web forms, I wish I would have gotten into it sooner ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a controller to render the view.

For instance, if you had an `AdminController` with a method similar to something like `public ActionResult Index() { return View(); }` this would render the `index` view where you could place your html/links etc.

The view itself doesn't need a `model` this way as you are not supplying anything when returning the `View()`.

You could then navigate to the page by `http://xxx/Admin/Index` or, 'http://xxx/Admin/'.

It is well worth looking around SO and other various websites for MVC queries!

Good luck.